# Retain content while deleting user using services

Tags: 7, users, services

I need to delete a user account using [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module & does it fine.

I can see that content(forum) created/updated by the user gets deleted.

Is it possible to achieve below screenshot option via services module in drupal 7?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question,

I have updated the default account setting of `when cancelling a user account` in the path `/admin/config/people/accounts` to `Delete the account and make its content belong to the Anonymous user`

Resolves my query.